# ASP.NET MVC5 Attribute routing - Ambiguous action exception with only one matching action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2019

I have a weird bug that keeps popping up, usually while debugging, where I will get one route throwing this exception out of nowhere, and will continue for that route until I stop debugging. Weird thing is I only have one action that would ever match, and only one action with that name, only controller, etc.

My question is, has anyone come across such weird behavior? Any fixes? This has persisted after a repair install of Visual Studio 2019, reboots, etc. I think its an issue with the project but I can't find anything with a google search and I have no clue where to even begin looking. There's no way it's matching against the fallback route in the RouteConfig.cs AND the attribute route, right?

Update: Happened even following suggestions to clean up the similar routes in routeconfig.cs, happening on a seperate controller (another attribute routed controller). Details added below.

> The current request is ambiguous between the following action methods:
>
> System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Getquestions(System.String, System.String, System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection) on type >Origin2.Controllers.Events2.Events2APIController
>
> System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Getquestions(System.String, System.String, System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection) on type >Origin2.Controllers.Events2.Events2APIController

Trimmed down controller:

```
using ...


namespace Origin2.Controllers.Events2
{

    [RoutePrefix("app/api/Events")]


    public class Events2APIController : Controller
    {

        [Route("{code}/questions/GET")]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Getquestions(string code, string mode, FormCollection collection)
        {
            //CODE LIVES HERE. 
        }

        protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            ExceptionNotifications.SendNotice(filterContext, null, "Events2 API Controller");
        }


    }

}
```

Trimmed down routeconfig.cs

```
using Origin2.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
namespace Origin2
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); //Attribute Routing Enabled


            //External
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "External",
                url: "app/external/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "External", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "app",
                url: "app/{action}/{*id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "app", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "app2",
                url: "app/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "app", action = "Index" }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DefaultApp",
                url: "app/{controller}/{action}/{**id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "app", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DefaultApp2",
                url: "app/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "app", action = "Index" }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DebugShorthand",
                url: "debug",
                defaults: new { controller = "app", action = "Debug" }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "RootAddress",
                url: "",
                defaults: new { controller = "app", action = "Index" }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DefaultOrigin1",
                url: "app/{*url}",
                defaults: new { controller = "app", action = "SendToOrigin1" }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

After fixing routeconfig.cs's ambiguous route.

> The current request is ambiguous between the following action methods:
>
> System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult EventLanding(System.String) on type Origin2.Controllers.Events2.Events2Controller
>
> System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult EventLanding(System.String) on type Origin2.Controllers.Events2.Events2Controller

Trimmed down Events2Controller:

```
using Origin2.Models;
using Origin2.Models.Events2;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using static Origin2.Models.Events2.EventRoles;

namespace Origin2.Controllers.Events2
{
   [RoutePrefix("app/Events")]
   [Route("{action=index}")] 

  public class Events2Controller : Controller
    {

        [Route("{code}")]
        public ActionResult EventLanding(string code)
        {
            //This will be the public facing thank you handler for all signup activities. 
            if (code.ToUpper() == "AAABD") 
            {
                return View("EventLandingCustom_AAABD");
            }
            return View();
        }

        protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            ExceptionNotifications.SendNotice(filterContext, null, "Events2 Controller");

            // Redirect on error:
            //filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("Error", "Index");
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Controllers are found by reflection; do you have another (perhaps now outdated/renamed) assembly hanging around in your bin folder which contains the same controller?

Comment: Can you explain which route you use that causes this error, and please show us the route.config as well.

Comment: This was a POST to 'https://localhost:44326/app/api/Events/aaaba/questions/get', added a trimmed down route config.

Comment: @sellotape, I dug around a bit, only found a ton of .net assemblies and the one for this app, as well as copies in the obj folder, everything looked ok in ildasm...

Comment: @ChrisWhipple Making a guess here, routes DefaultApp and/or DefaultApp2 might be colliding with AttributeRouting.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that, I would have thought the error would have mentioned route names, I will give this a shot and come back if it happens again. This happens after debugging for awhile, so I wont know for sure if it is fixed for awhile.

Comment: So after adjusting it happened randomly again, I updated the post with new details.

Answer (score 0):

I think these two routes are identical

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DefaultApp",
            url: "app/{controller}/{action}/{**id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "app", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DefaultApp2",
            url: "app/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "app", action = "Index" }
```

try commenting out one of these.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that, I would have thought the error would have mentioned route names, I will give this a shot and come back if it happens again. This happens after debugging for awhile, so I wont know for sure if it is fixed for awhile.

Comment: Route error don't mention route names.In both the route the required parameters are same and optional parameter does not contribute to the route uniqueness since it's optional.